# Sanic instance named 'rasa_sdk.endpoint' uses an invalid format

Tags: rasa

Installed Rasa 3.0 using https://github.com/gerasimos/doc-rasa-on-m1

MacOS 12.2.2 (M1)
Python 3.9

Running the default model created at the time of setup.

Ran `rasa run actions` inside actions folder - heres the output :

rasa run actions --debug /Users/mohit/miniforge3/envs/rasa3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sanic_cors/extension.py:39: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.   SANIC_VERSION = LooseVersion(sanic_version) 2022-07-10 17:37:52 INFO     rasa_sdk.endpoint  - Starting action endpoint server... Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/mohit/miniforge3/envs/rasa3/bin/rasa", line 8, in 
sys.exit(main())   File "/Users/mohit/miniforge3/envs/rasa3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rasa/**main**.py", line 119, in main
cmdline_arguments.func(cmdline_arguments)   File "/Users/mohit/miniforge3/envs/rasa3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rasa/cli/run.py", line 59, in run_actions
sdk.main_from_args(args)   File "/Users/mohit/miniforge3/envs/rasa3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rasa_sdk/**main**.py", line 18, in main_from_args
run(   File "/Users/mohit/miniforge3/envs/rasa3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rasa_sdk/endpoint.py", line 139, in run
app = create_app(   File "/Users/mohit/miniforge3/envs/rasa3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rasa_sdk/endpoint.py", line 77, in create_app
app = Sanic(**name**, configure_logging=False)   File "/Users/mohit/miniforge3/envs/rasa3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sanic/app.py", line 177, in **init**
super().**init**(name=name)   File "/Users/mohit/miniforge3/envs/rasa3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sanic/base/root.py", line 37, in **init**
raise SanicException( sanic.exceptions.SanicException: Sanic instance named 'rasa_sdk.endpoint' uses an invalid format. Names must begin with a character and may only contain alphanumeric characters,
_, or -.

What name is it talking about ?
The endpoints.yml file has only the default commented code.
Please help me understand what is this issue about ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from you trying to run the actions when you're in the `[project]/action` dir. You have to be in the `[project]` sir only.
Also, this problem belongs to the rasa forum: forum.rasa.com and not stackoverflow.

Comment: If you think a question doesn't belong on Stack Overflow, please do not answer it. Once you've reached 50 reputation points, [you can leave a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on the question.

Comment: I only have 1 point, I'll have to answer more questions for now before I can get to 50.